# capture and compare 2 json results

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid that uses ajax/json to load data, then i have a function that runs every 15 sec to check if the data has changed, if it has i need to upload the data from the jqgrid, the problem im having is that my 2 calls return the same result but when i compare them i get that they are diferent, the only diference i can find isnt on the data, is on the parameters from the call since jqgrid adds parameters like _search, page, order, etc but they have no efect on the result.

when the grid makes a call i store the data on a gloval var (part of my grid code):

```
jQuery("#scheduledGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '../Agenda/turneraJSON',
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
        'fecha': function () { return $("#selectedDate").val(); },
        'idTipoConsulta': function () { return $("#idTipoTurnoSeleccionado").val(); },
        'idEspecialidad': function () { return $("#idEspecialidadSeleccionada").val(); },
        'idEstado': function () { return $("#idEstadoSeleccionado").val(); }
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        tempData = data;},
```

then i have another call

```
  window.setInterval(function () {
            chkUpdates();
        }, 15000);

    function chkUpdates() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '../Agenda/turneraJSON',
            datatype: "json",
            data: {
                fecha: function () { return $("#selectedDate").val(); },
                idTipoConsulta: function () { return $("#idTipoTurnoSeleccionado").val(); },
                idEspecialidad: function () { return $("#idEspecialidadSeleccionada").val(); },
                idEstado: function () { return $("#idEstadoSeleccionado").val(); }
            }                
        }).done(function (msg) {
            tempData2 = msg;
            if (tempData2 == tempData) {
                alert("yes");
            }
            else {
                alert("no");
                //refreshGrid();
            }

        });
```

the problem is that  `if (tempData2 == tempData)` is false all the time

any idea?

Comment: You've verified that the first call that sets tempData returns and sets the value of tempData before the second call that does the compare?

Comment: yep y compare the values from tempData and tempData2 on firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare two different objects. Try convert them to string and compare :

```
if(JSON.stringify(tempData)==JSON.stringify(tempData2))
```

Comment: yep, i did that yesterday and was to lazy to make an answer lol